# How do you make Date Modified exact?

Tags: 2007, timestamp

I'm using the Date Modified column in my Notes list (a Task list), but the time that it defaults to is rounded up to the nearest hour or so.

How do I get the Date Modified to have timestamp behaviour and be exact to at least the minute (though seconds would be better)?

**EDIT:**  In the end, it was brought to my attention, that the `Modified` column does exactly what I want (to the minute), so I went with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to enforce the displaying of minutes and seconds with a DataViewWebPart in SharePoint Designer, and using ddwrt:FormatDateTime() XSLT method on your Date Modified field.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying the task list on my environment and the modified date is rounded to the minute (not the hour).

The only way that you can get the the seconds (without writing a custom solution) is by exporting to excel and from excel change the cell format to display the seconds.

Hope this helps!

Renzo